# C# Projectile Simulator - Applying Speed to X Position of Projectile Physics

Tags: c#, winforms, math, physics, projectile

First of all, here is the code:

```
decimal gravity = decimal.Parse(gforce.Text) / 1000;
        decimal speed = decimal.Parse(initialSpeed.Text) / 1000;

        decimal newAngle = DegreesToRadians(decimal.Parse(angle.Text));
        double doubleNewAngle = (double)newAngle;
        decimal Px = Math.Round(((decimal)Math.Cos(doubleNewAngle) * 0.001M), 13);
        decimal Py = Math.Round(((decimal)Math.Sin(doubleNewAngle) * 0.001M), 13);

        string PxTemp = "";

        for(decimal t = 0.001M; Py > 0; t = t + 0.001M)
        {
            gravity = gravity + gravity * 0.001M;
            Py = Py + speed - gravity;

            Px = (Px + speed * Px);

            graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Magenta, 10f), 45 + (float)Px, 475 - (float)Py, 1, 1, 0, 360);

            try
            {
                graphics.DrawArc(new Pen(Color.Magenta, 10f), 45 + (float)Px, 475 - (float)Py, 1, 1, 0, 360);
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Px: " + Px.ToString() + " Py: " + Py.ToString(), "Error");
                this.Close();
            }
```

I am attempting to create a projectile simulator, I have successfully created the effect of gravity and acceleration on the y-axis. But however when applying the speed to the x axis(making the speed depend on the angle) I am having trouble. I can make it so every second the projectile moves 1 metre but for it to be correct the projectiles' speed across the x-axis should depend on the speed AND THE ANGLE.

To achieve this I have done:

```
Px = Px + (speed * Px)
```

Where Px is the value of distance across the axis Cosine of the angle:

```
decimal Px = Math.Round(((decimal)Math.Cos(doubleNewAngle) * 0.001M), 13);
```

When I do

```
Px = Px + (speed * Px)
```

The value returns some huge number for example 4412651515851.41214244121, I at first assumed this was because Px was going beyond its precision point but any rounding attempts I have made have failed, How should I achieve a correct Px number?

Here is an image to visualise it:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have been struggling all day and I couldn't find anything on-line. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a useful tool to help workout the proper calculations.http://www.mrmont.com/teachers/physicsteachershelper-proj.html

Answer (score 2):

The laws of motion are very different to the ones you use:

```
y'' = -g --> y(t) = y0 + vy0*t - g/2*t*t
x'' =  0 --> x(t) = x0 + vx0*t
```

These are the solutions for motion without air friction. Most complications of the equation of motion require numerical integration of the ODE.

The initial velocities `vx0,vy0` are what you initially compute in `Px,Py`. But probably you should use

```
vx0 = speed*cos(angle)
vy0 = speed*sin(angle)
```

to get the initial velocity compatible with the inputs. Some additional unit conversions may be required.

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn't mention that I have created a function to convert degrees to radians. And thanks for the better formula, we haven't done calculus or any physics at school yet so I just used that simpler version.

Comment: No, my sorry, I read over the `DegreeToRadians` invocation. Removed that part.

Comment: Maybe if I can get this X-axis speed to work I will fix that formula stuff up.

Comment: You should notice that you get an exponential function for Px and gravity in your original code, looking like `Px = Px0*(1+speed*dt)^(t/dt) =^= Px0*exp(speed*t)`. Apart from the fact that the argument of `exp` should be dimensionless, this is extremely unphysical, since the horizontal speed also increases exponentially.

Comment: How does the horizontal speed increase or decrease, I will not be including air resistance so the x-speed should stay constant until ground friction is introduced.

Comment: In the equations in the answer, the horizontal speed is constant. Of course the whole motion ends resp. changes fundamentally once the y coordinate hits ground level.

Comment: Just to cear things up, could you help me identify what the variables are in these equations: y'' = -g --> y(t) = y0 + vy0*t - g/2*t*t
x'' =  0 --> x(t) = x0 + vx0*t

Comment: `x,y` is obviously the position. Their time derivative `(vx,vy)=(x',y')` is the velocity. The velocity at time zero, `(vx0,vy0)` is defined by the inputs `speed` and `angle`. The horizontal acceleration `x''` is zero since there is no horizontal force. Vertically there is gravity pointing down, thus `y''=-g`. Integrating twice gives the formulas.